# Using cached images in UItableView

Tags: iphone

using iOS 4.1 SDK. I am using 2 small images in each row of a UITableView. I wanted to know which of the following 2 methods was better, also is Method 1 valid at all?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   // create the images amd assign to class member variable
   NSString *imgStr1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someImg1"                                                                         
                                                     ofType:@"png"];
   UIImage* img1 =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgStr];
   self.image1 = img1;
   [img1 release];

   NSString *imgStr2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someImg2"                                                                         
                                                     ofType:@"png"];
   UIImage* img2 =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgStr2];
   self.image2 = img2;
   [img2 release];


}

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: 
                         cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {

       //create image views here
       ..........................
     }

    / assign images from viewDidLoad to imageView here
     UIImageView *img1View = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImg1Tag];
     [img1View setImage:self.img1];
     etc....
  }
```

OR should i just do this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    [img1View setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would go with `imageNamed:` as it will cache the two images and properly respond to memory warning situations.

Method one is valid, but there is little difference between it and using `imageNamed:`. Images created with `imageNamed:` will be cleared out if the device needs to reclaim memory. Unless you clear the images created in method one yourself when you receive a memory warning they will stay in memory.

It's also less code and less that you have to worry about, which is always better. Less code == less bugs.

Comment: but i've created those images in viewDidLoad so why it will have to create from disk, i thought method 1 maybe better for performance but am unsure whether you can assign that class member image (self.img1) to multiple imageviews in the rows

Comment: You're right, I missed that, sorry. Either way, the second part of my answer still stands - when you get a memory warning, unless you clear out the images you created from disk, they will hang around, where as UIImage's cache will handle that for you if you use `imageNamed:`. Practically, there is little difference betweenw aht you're doing here and using `imageNamed:` other than the fact that the latter is less code and handles things so you don't have to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use `UIImage`'s `imageNamed:` method, which loads the image from the app bundle and keeps it in cache.

This way you would only have to set the cell's UIImageView's image to `[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Another point, if you cell has many subviews, I think subclassing it and adding different subviews as class properties is better. Then you only have to cast it when getting it from `dequeueReusableCell` and it allows you to modify subviews without using tags and casting everytime.